# What's happening with this button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

ENTIRE LIVE CODE: http://jsfiddle.net/9GWtT/

HTML CODE:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form>
        <fieldset><p>
            <label>Username: <input type="text" name="user" id="user" /></label></p><br /><p>
            <label>Password: <input type="password" name="passw" id ="passw" /></label></p>
            <label><input type="submit" value="Log in" name="submitBUT" class="regbut" id="submitBUT" /><div id="helllo"></div></label>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
```

CSS CODE:

```
input.regbut {
    width: 65px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #3C0;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 7px;
  //-moz-border-radius: 7px;
    border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-right: 1px solid #777;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
}
input.regbut:hover {
    border-top: 1px solid #777;
    border-left: 1px solid #777;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}
input.regbut:active {
    background-color: #390;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
var subBut = document.getElementById('submitBUT');
var users = ['hithere', 'Peter112', 'Geksj', 'lOsja', 'fInduS', '323DssaAA', 'f1fsus'];
var passes = ['mllesl', 'Petboy', 'Heneeesh', 'Olga', '234dasdf77/', 'minls', 'ew832ja'];
var output = [];

function submi(u, p) {
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        if (users[i] == u) {
            output.push(i);
        }
    }
    for (var o = 0; o < output.length; o++) {
        if (passes[output[o]] == p) {
            return p + ' was a correct password.';
        }
    }
    return 'Error, please try again';
}
subBut.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('helllo').innerHTML =
    submi(document.getElementById('user').value, document.getElementById('passw').value);
    return false;
};
```

Okay, so the button works nicely at first, but then after you click it once, the :hover property suddenly happens far outside of the button itself, even when you're hovering over the text in the label that appears after you click the button. Why is this??

Comment: What's your browser? See no anomalies in FF.

Comment: **Please** include *relevant* code **in the question**, as I mentioned last time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570049/whats-wrong-in-this-javascript-code

Comment: Really? Have you tried doing what I said? Click it once first, and then try.

Comment: @T.J. - Perhaps OP is confused as to what code is actually relevant.  In this case the markup he provided should suffice.

Comment: Oh you mean that. It's because you slap the message inside the same label as the input. (OP has noticed hovering over the added message after clicking will inherit the CSS from the input within the same <label>

Comment: @Derek: When I posted that comment, there was no code or markup *whatsoever* in the question.

Comment: @T.J. - gotcha - figured as much.  When i got here there was markup/JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `<div id="helllo"></div>` for the result outside of the label for the button:
http://jsfiddle.net/pgS5j/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're use of the label element might be the cause here.  I have only used/seen the label element used *next* to an input

Try organizing your html like so...

(I prefer my forms in DL but its really up to you.)

```
<dl>
<dt>Username:</dt>
<dd><input type="text" id="userName" /><label for="#userName" /></dd>
<dt>Password:</dt>
<dd><input type="password" id="pass" /><label for="#pass" /></dd>
<dt></dt>
<dd><input type="submit" name="formSubmit" id="formSubmit" /><div id="hello"></div></dd>
</dl>
```

*(Although i believe simply removing the input elements from your labels and putting them NEXT to your inputs would do the trick)*

Comment: The OP's use of labels is correct as far as placement goes. Wrapping the form control in a label gives that label implicit association with the control and makes the `for` attribute unnecessary. W3C: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1

Comment: Looking at again at the changes you recommended: Your example actually takes the label ("Username:", "Password:") and moves it *out* of the label element and into a definition term element instead, leaving the label element empty and serving no purpose. Using definition list markup or not, you've negated the value of using the label element entirely.

Comment: @steve - Interesting, i've just never seen that form of markup (hence i `believe`).  I was simply demonstrating how I'd organize the markup - not how to display an actual message via a label... which can be modified via JS.

Comment: Also, OP isn't even using a label for that message (edited to reflect that).  As `codethis` pointed out, removing the `#message` div from the label does the trick.

Comment: My comments seem to have been misunderstood, which I assume is my own fault. Ignore the OP and displaying messages for the moment. The issue is `Username:` is the content for the `<label>` -- it's the *label* for the "userName" input. So your code would be written as follows: `<dt><label for="userName">Username:</label></dt>`. I hope that's a little clearer. I'm not trying to attack you here, just trying to be constructive.